# Error commiting an image in docker

Tags: docker

I am learning docker and while I was trying to commit my image I get this error

```
docker commit ccaa6f1933e Serret/FirstApp:1.0
invalid reference format
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seem to be that for consistency docker does not allow the capitalization of the names of the images

```
docker commit ccaa6f1933e serret/firstapp:1.0
```

when I did this it work perfectly